# SurfaceHolder (Activity crash)

Tags: android

I have a problem and it is: I go to the Activity, then go back to the menu, and then I try again go to the same Activity from the menu. In the second attempt I get an error "Out of memory" and Choreographer.class opens with an arrow at line after mCallbacksRunning = true; }

```
void doCallbacks(int callbackType, long frameTimeNanos) {
        CallbackRecord callbacks;
        synchronized (mLock) {
            // We use "now" to determine when callbacks become due because it's possible
            // for earlier processing phases in a frame to post callbacks that should run
            // in a following phase, such as an input event that causes an animation to start.
            final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            callbacks = mCallbackQueues[callbackType].extractDueCallbacksLocked(now);
            if (callbacks == null) {
                return;
            }
            mCallbacksRunning = true;
        }
        try {
            for (CallbackRecord c = callbacks; c != null; c = c.next) {
                if (DEBUG) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "RunCallback: type=" + callbackType
                            + ", action=" + c.action + ", token=" + c.token
                            + ", latencyMillis=" + (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - c.dueTime));
                }
                c.run(frameTimeNanos);
            }
```

Short code of Activity:

```
public class Test extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
public Test(Context context) {
 super(context);
 getHolder().addCallback(this);
}

         public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
     updateThread = new UT(this);
     updateThread.setRunning(true);
     updateThread.start();
     }

     public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) { 
     }

     public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {    
     boolean retry = true;
     updateThread.setRunning(false);
     while (retry) {
     try {updateThread.join();
     retry = false; } 
     catch (InterruptedException e) {
     }
     }
     }
    }
```

And Update Tread:

```
public class UT extends Thread {

 private long time;
 private final int fps = 20;
 private boolean toRun = false;
 private Test Test;
 private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

 public UT(Test rTest) {
 Test = rTest;
 surfaceHolder = Test.getHolder();
 }

 public void setRunning(boolean run) {
 toRun = run;
 }

 @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
@Override
 public void run() {
 Canvas c;
 while (toRun) {

 long cTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

 if ((cTime - time) <= (1000 / fps)) {

 c = null;
 try {
 c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
 Test.onDraw(c);
 } finally {

 if (c != null) {
 surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
 }
 }
 }
 time = cTime;
 }
 }
}
```

Comment: please reformat your code.

Comment: Not sure what the exact problem is, but note that your update thread is going to present a couple of issues for you and could be related to what you're seeing.  First, it's basically sitting in a tight loop with no sleep or block.  This is going to cause the CPU to be in continuous use and drain battery unnecessarily.  Second, because of the tight loop, there is a race condition where your `surfaceDestroyed()` callback is called and sets the flag in the thread, but the thread could already be attempting to lock a surface which no longer exists.

Comment: Ok, I'll look for alternatives for Update Threads.